# onclick not working with button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a javascript function work on pressing search button but the function doesnt seem to run. Please guide. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5fRC/).

```
<form action="" method="get" id="searchform" >
    <input name="q" type="text" id="search" size="32" maxlength="128" class="txt"/>
    <input type="submit" id="hit" value="Search" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn"/>
</form>
```

Heres the JS,

```
function myFunction() {
 alert("I am an alert box!");
}
```

Comment: Try `onclick="myFunction();return false"` but this will stop your form working.

Comment: As oliver said, if you do the `return false;` your JS should execute, but it will prevent the submission from continuing so your form will not submit.

Comment: Shouldn't the handler run anyway, then submit the form?

Comment: @AdamPlocher: Its actually an on page search so I do not want to post the results anywhere but I need the value of the input in the function I am calling.

Comment: Fahad, can you use a `<input type="button" />` instead of `type="submit"`?  Button will look the same, but will not cause the form to submit.

Comment: @AdamPlocher: Tried with the button too but the problem still exists:http://jsfiddle.net/X5fRC/2/

Comment: @Kolink: I do not want to submit the form.

Comment: Are you able to get this to work outside of js fiddle?

Comment: @Gohn67:No. I haven't

Comment: sourcecode and alfasin have working fiddle examples. I tried both. They are correct that it had to do with one of your JSFiddle settings. Did those not work for you?

Comment: if anyone use the click() it will not works, because it reserved keyword, try with click1() instead of click(). For understanding purpose I give the name click1()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have wrapped the function in the body, `onLoad`, just change it to no wrap - in `<head>`. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/X5fRC/3/) fiddle.

```
function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
}

};
^^
```

You also have an extra `};` in your code,

**UPDATE:**

This happens because:

- if the function is place inside `$(document).ready`, then it can only be **used within the ready callback** (and in the inner objects). You can't reference it outside.
- but if you are placing it outside the ready function then **it gets global scope**, i.e. you can call it from anywhere.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between the two?

Comment: try after wrapping your above function in $(document).ready() of js,it will not get executed , but if you place it outside it , it will start firing...

Comment: furthermore if the function has an javascript internal function name (e.g.: close() ) then it wont work.. had this problem today and realized that close() is overwritten by JS

Answer (score 6):

The following works for me:

```
        <form action="" method="get" id="searchform" >
          <input name="q" type="text" id="search" size="32" maxlength="128" class="txt"  >
          <input type="submit" id="hit" value="Search" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn">
        </form>
        <script>
           function myFunction() {
              alert("I am an alert box!");
           }
        </script>
```

but I noticed that you have a `};` at the end of your question - maybe that's the thing that causes a syntax error ?

**UPDATE:**

The problem was (besides the `};` ) with the setup of your fiddler. Check **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/X5fRC/8/)** out!

Comment: Your updated Fiddle example worked for me. Maybe you can explain what setting you changed and why it worked. I figured it out, but I was unclear at first.

Comment: @Gohn67 Checkout the left menu of your fiddler vs. mine. It's easy to see the diff in the settings.

Comment: Yeah, I know what the difference is. I already upvoted your answer. I was just suggesting that you explain in your answer so future visitors and Fahad Uddin, know the difference. Thanks.

Comment: @Gohn67 cause onLoad loads the function on body load which is unnecessary in our case, but also cause this fiddler apparently has a bug with the onLoad() settings: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar

Answer (score 3):

It seems most likely to me that you have a syntax error somewhere in your JavaScript file. The reason I say this is because there's nothing that would stop the alert from appearing using the code you've shown.

Check the browser's error console (F12 in IE and Chrome) and see if there are any errors, as these will stop the function from being defined.

Comment: Thanks. There is an error that say that myFunction is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at your fiddle, it has an extra closed bracket. This should work.

```
 function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
    return false;
 };
```

Your fiddle looked like this:

```
 function myFunction() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
    } 
};
```

**EDIT 1:**
I added a `return false` since the user did not want to submit the form.

**EDIT 2:**

Since no one wants to explain the JS Fiddle issue, I'll take a stab it.

In the original JS Fiddle, "onLoad", is used on the second dropdown on the sidebar menu.

The reason this setting does not work is that JS Fiddle executes the javascript code in an onload function. This means that myFunction is out of scope.

This is why you need to use either "No wrap - in " and "No wrap - in " options in the dropdown menu. By using those two options instead, your function `myFunction` will be in the global scope.

I hope that clarifies things.

**Edit 3**

If you did want to use the onload event. You could add a click event handler instead and remove the `onclick` attribute in your submit button markup.

In general it is probably better to set up your event handlers using javascript.

```
document.getElementById('hit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
});
```

If you wanted to use jQuery, you could do this:

```
$('#hit').click(function() {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your function in `try-catch` block...should work

```
function myFunction() {
    try {    
        alert("I am an alert box!");
        //enter code here
        return false;
    }
    catch (err) {
        txt = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
        txt += "Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
        txt += "Click OK to continue.\n\n";
        alert(txt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="button" id="hit" value="Search" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn"/>
```

change the `<input type="submit" />` to `<input type="button" />`

when clicking the input type submit, the from will submit instead of working the function.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.