# "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to redirect my window in base a value of button but i can get work

this is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>Click the button to change the location of the first iframe element (index 0).</p>

  <button class="godd" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <br>
  <br>

  <iframe src="http://localhost:8005/?xform=http://127.0.0.1:8080/output_path4fff"></iframe>
  <iframe src="http://localhost:8005/?xform=http://127.0.0.1:8080/output_path4fff"></iframe>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">
    $(document).ready(myFunction() {
      var Vp = $('.godd').eq(0).text();
      window.frames[0].top.location.href = 'http://' + Vp;
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

please help

Comment: checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171008/onclick-not-working-with-button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jquery Code should be like following:

```
function myFunction()   {  /* myfunction declaration */
  var Vp = $('.godd').eq(0).text();  
  window.frames[0].top.location.href  = 'http://' + Vp ;
};
$(document).ready(function(){  /* DOM ready callback */

});
```

> You should define your function outside DOM ready. Read [**$(document).ready**](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Your script tag should be like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    //Jquery Code
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`script` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) can have a `src` attribute **or** content, but not both. If they have both, the content is ignored (the content is considered "script documentation," not code).

Use another script block for your jQuery script

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</script>
<script>
    function myFunction()   { 
    }
</script>
```

You need to define the function in Global scope  as you accessing it using inline click handler.

```
function myFunction()   { 
    var Vp = $('.godd').eq(0).text();  
    window.frames[0].top.location.href  = 'http://' + Vp ;
};
$(document).ready(function(){  
   // DOM ready callback         
});
```

---

However I would recommend should use unobtrusive event handler instead of inline click handler.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
   $('.godd').on('click', function()   {  
      var Vp = $(this).text();  //Current element context
      window.frames[0].top.location.href  = 'http://' + Vp ;
   });
});
```

*HTML*

```
<button class="godd">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

please call function on page ready below code. please check it once:

```
<script>
function myFunction(){ 
      var Vp = $('.godd').eq(0).text();  
      window.frames[0].top.location.href  = 'http://' + Vp ;
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 
   myFunction();
});
</script>
```